# Scala - differents between eventually timeout and Thread.sleep()

Tags: scala, scalatest, zio

I have some async (ZIO) code, which I need to test. If I create a testing part using `Thread.sleep()` it works fine and I always get response:

```
for {
 saved <- database.save(smth)
 result <- eventually {
   Thread.sleep(20000)
   database.search(...) 
 }
} yield result
```

But if I made same logic using `timeout` and `interval` from `eventually` then it never works correctly ( I got timeouts):

```
for {
   saved <- database.save(smth)
   result <- eventually(timeout(Span(20, Seconds)), interval(Span(20, Seconds))) {
     database.search(...) 
   }
} yield result
```

I do not understand why `timeout` and `interval` works different then `Thread.sleep`. It should be doing exactly same thing. Can someone explain it to me and tell how I should change this code to do not need to use `Thread.sleep()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `database.search(...)` returns `ZIO[]` object.

`eventually{database.search(...)}` most probably succeeds immediately after the first try.

It successfully created a task to query the database.
Then database is queried without any retry logic.

Regarding how to make it work:

```
val search: ZIO[Any, Throwable, String] = ???
val retried: ZIO[Any with Clock, Throwable, Option[String]] = search.retry(Schedule.spaced(Duration.fromMillis(1000))).timeout(Duration.fromMillis(20000))
```

Something like that should work. But I believe that more elegant solutions exist.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer from @simpadjo addresses the "what" quite succinctly. I'll add some additional context as to why you might see this behavior.

```
for {
  saved <- database.save(smth)
  result <- eventually {
    Thread.sleep(20000)
    database.search(...) 
  }
} yield result
```

There are three different technologies being mixed here which is causing some confusion.

First is [ZIO](https://zio.dev/) which is an asynchronous programming library that uses it's own custom runtime and execution model to perform tasks. The second is `eventually` which comes from [ScalaTest](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.8/org/scalatest/concurrent/Eventually.html) and is useful for checking asynchronous computations by effectively polling the state of a value. And thirdly, there is `Thread.sleep` which is a Java api that literally suspends the current thread and prevents task progression until the timer expires.

`eventually` uses a simple retry mechanism that differs based on whether you are using a normal value or a `Future` from the scala standard library. Basically it runs the code in the block and if it throws then it sleeps the current thread and then retries it based on some interval configuration, eventually timing out. Notably in this case the behavior is entirely synchronous, meaning that as long as the value in the `{}` doesn't throw an exception it won't keep retrying.

`Thread.sleep` is a heavy weight operation and in this case it is effectively blocking the function being passed to `eventually` from progressing for 20 seconds. Meaning that by the time the `database.search` is called the operation has likely completed.

The second variant is different, it executes the code in the `eventually` block immediately, if it throws an exception then it will attempt it again based on the interval/timeout logic that your provide. In this scenario the save may not have completed (or propagated if it is eventually consistent). Because you are returning a `ZIO` which is designed *not* to throw, and `eventually` doesn't understand `ZIO` it will simply return the `search` attempt with no retry logic.

The accepted answer:

```
val retried: ZIO[Any with Clock, Throwable, Option[String]] = search.retry(Schedule.spaced(Duration.fromMillis(1000))).timeout(Duration.fromMillis(20000))
```

works because the `retry` and `timeout` are using the built-in `ZIO` operators which *do* understand how to actually `retry` and `timeout` a `ZIO`. Meaning that if search fails the `retry` will handle it until it succeeds.